# Do poor converts get priority in tzedakah/maaser

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes, yoreh-deah

In Halacha, is there any priority in giving converts, with the Halacha status of ani/poor,  tzedakah and Maaser before giving it to poor born Jews? The reason I ask is because there are more positive  mitzvoth for Jews to love the convert than to love the  average fellow Jew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SA in [YD 251:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.251.9?lang=bi) states clearly that a convert comes after a Jew, provided that they are both at the same level of Torah:

> היו לפניו עניים הרבה ואין בכיס לפרנס או לכסות או לפדות את כולם מקדים הכהן ללוי והלוי לישראל והישראל לחלל והחלל לשתוקי והשתוקי לאסופי והאסופי לממזר והממזר לנתין **והנתין לגר והגר לעבד** משוחרר במה דברים אמורים בזמן שהם שוים בחכמה אבל אם היה ממזר ת"ח וכ"ג עם הארץ ממזר תלמיד חכם קודם (ואפילו חכם לכסות ועם הארץ להחיות ואשת חבר כחבר) (ב"י מהירושלמי) וכל הגדול בחכמה קודם לחבירו ואם היה אחד מהם רבו או אביו אע"פ שיש שם גדול מהם בחכמה רבו או אביו שהוא תלמיד חכם קודם לזה שהוא גדול ממנו

> If many poor seek help and there is not enough money in the treasury to help them all, a priest is given preference before a Levite; a Levite before an ordinary Israelite; an Israelite before a Halal; a Halal before a child of unknown fatherhood; such a one before a foundling; a foundling before a bastard; a bastard before a Nathin; **a Nathin before a proselyte; a proselyte before an emancipated slave**. This applies only in case they are equal in learning. But between a bastard a scholar and a high priest an ignoramus, the scholarly bastard is given the preference; and so whosoever is greater in learning is preferred. However, if the father or teacher of the charity distributor is among the poor seeking aid, the teacher, or the father (provided he too is a scholar) is given the preference, even if there is a far greater scholar among them (Sefaria)